# ¿Cómo adquirió "tarifar" su significado coloquial?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos

El otro día usé la expresión "salir tarifando" con el sentido de "terminar discutiendo" y tuve que explicarla. Tras unas consultas al DLE posteriores aprendí que en efecto, "tarifar" es, en el sentido coloquial, "reñir con alguien".

> **[tarifar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZCORoLr)**
>
> 1. tr. Señalar o aplicar una tarifa.
> 2. intr. coloq. **Reñir con alguien, enemistarse.**

Me pareció curioso que sin embargo en el nombre asociado a este verbo no se encuentra una definición análoga

> [**tarifa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZCKWPFd)
>   Del ár. hisp. *ta‘rífa*, y este del ár. clás. *ta‘rīfah*, de *ta‘rīf* 'definición'.
>
> 1. f. Tabla de precios, derechos o cuotas tributarias.
> 2. f. Precio unitario fijado por las autoridades para los servicios públicos realizados a su cargo.
> 3. f. Montante que se paga por un servicio público.

Esperaba encontrar en "tarifa" una entrada con la acepción de "riña" o "pelea". Comprobando la etimología de este nombre, se entiende que no tenga tal acepción, ni siquiera como coloquialismo.

Entonces, ¿cómo adquirió "tarifar" su significado coloquial de "reñir o enemistarse con alguien"?

Comment: Me sorprende que las definiciones no indiquen que son de uso regional. Nunca he oído esa palabra con ese sentido.

Comment: Me pregunto de dónde eres, si es una expresión para ti común; y dónde es que no se te entendió.

Comment: Solo se hace "pagar" (imponer una "tarifa") a los que no nos gustan.....

Answer (score 1):

Parece que **tarifar** aparece por primera vez en en el Diccionario de Terreros y Pando (1788) indicandolo como sinónimo jocoso de "reñir".

> [image]

mientras que la acepción **señalar o aplicar una tarifa** no aparece hasta más de 100 años despues (diccionario de Zerolo: 1895, que lo califica como "neologismo"):

[image]

Esto indica que, al menos en los diccionarios, el proceso fue al revés de lo supuesto: no es que a **señalar o aplicar una tarifa** se le añadiera el de **reñir**, sino al revés.

Por otro lado el CORDE no recoge más que un par de casos de uso, ambos en el siglo XX, por lo que no es de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Una mera sugerencia “sobrevenida”. ¿No habrá una referencia a Tarifa, la plaza “fronteriza” española tan cargada de historia? Como se suele decir, ahí lo dejo.

Alfredo J R

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. ¿Podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/22804)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puede tener que ver con la percepción popular en España de que la "amistad" es algo así como un intercambio gratuito de favores. De aquí el no cobrar los servicios a los "amigos" a diferencia de la tarifa que se cobra a desconocidos.

Estos "amigos" son del tipo "hay que tener amigos hasta en el infierno (ja ja)", es decir amigos de intercambio de favores, y no amigos verdaderos.

Habiendo desavenencias, tiene sentido que "acabar tarifando" sea equivalente a reñir, enfadarse y acabar la tal "amistad".